# Pandas - Unstack to Top Column Level

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[10,20,30,40,50], 'Col2':[60,70,80,90,100]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','A','A','B','B'], [1,2,3,4,5]]))
```

I would like to obtain the following:

```
'A'                'B' 
'Col1'  'Col2'    'Col1'   'Col2'
 10      60        NaN      NaN
 20      70        NaN      NaN
 30      80        NaN      NaN 
 NaN     NaN       40       90 
 NaN     NaN       50       100
```

I tried using `df.unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)` but this results in:

```
'A'     'B'       'A'      'B' 
'Col1'  'Col1'    'Col2'   'Col2'
10      NaN        60      NaN
20      NaN        70      NaN
30      NaN        80      NaN
NaN     40         NaN     90
NaN     50         NaN     100
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) the index of `level=0` on `axis=1` and you would have your desired view:

```
df.unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
   A           B       
   Col1  Col2  Col1   Col2
1  10.0  60.0   NaN    NaN
2  20.0  70.0   NaN    NaN
3  30.0  80.0   NaN    NaN
4   NaN   NaN  40.0   90.0
5   NaN   NaN  50.0  100.0
```